# iis7 Access is denied on asp.net application

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

I publish my asp.net web site and deploy it to iis-7 locally on my windows 7 system.
After deployment when I write the address `localhost/applicationfoldername` in browser it gives me this error message:

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access is denied. (Exception from
>   HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)) .

what can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: Can the application pool account access the site folder? Can you post the IIS logs?

Comment: Ensure that you have published correctly. Follow the steps http://itzonesl.blogspot.com/2013/01/adding-your-site-to-iis-7.html

Comment: IIS Log:
#Software: Microsoft Internet Information Services 7.5
#Version: 1.0
#Date: 2013-04-04 10:44:31
#Fields: date time s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status time-taken
2013-04-04 10:44:31 ::1 GET /FilesBackupUtility1/ - 80 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+rv:13.0)+Gecko/20100101+Firefox/13.0.1 500 0 0 1684
2013-04-04 10:45:17 ::1 GET /FilesBackupUtility1/ - 80 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+rv:13.0)+Gecko/20100101+Firefox/13.0.1 500 0 0 19016

Comment: Try changing application pool identity to NETWORK SERVICE